# Retrieve json key with special characters

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I need to retrieve a JSON key which contains special characters, my JSON example is as follows.

```
{"profile":"dev","appconf:[classpath:/application.yml]":{"a.b":value,"x.y":value}
```

Please can someone provide example code to retrieve value of this key.

```
appconf:[classpath:/application.yml]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use bracket notation:

```
var value = myJsonData["appconf:[classpath:/appliation.ytml]"];
```

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that it didn't have anything to do with AngularJS.  Just a FYI in case you want to update your answer to reflect the edit to the question.